# htaccess - mod headers not working on a single file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

I have `.htaccess` file with the following lines (along with other rules):

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always append X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
```

This lines are working for every file I checked except my main page (which is the most important one)

`mod_headers` is enabled

This are the headers I get on the response (maybe one of them is conflicting):

[image: Headers received]

This is what I get for other request ( note the last 2 headers)

[image]

Comment: add more details, in case of, are you using php-fpm, some proxy things to generate your home? java? have you tried other pages generated by the same engine than your home?

Comment: I'm using php for the server side
As I wrote - it is working for other pages - it seems not to work for text/html pages

Comment: be precise, is the problem for all text/html pages generated via php or only for the home page? And how are you using php, php-fpm or mod_php, which php version? what is the apache version? where is your .htaccess and where are your php files?

Comment: The once that was generated using php. I use cgi - and it seems to be the issue as I saw here: http://serverfault.com/questions/383011/mod-headers-not-sending-headers-when-file-is-php